# 3D Touch: Presenting From Current VC

Tags: ios, swift, 3dtouch

I've successfully implemented a 3D Touch shortcut from the home screen using this code in the app delegate:

```
@objc(application:performActionForShortcutItem:completionHandler:) @available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application (_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler completionHandle: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    if shortcutItem.type == "com.myAppName.addtask" {
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let editorVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myVC_ID") as! myVC_Class
        let rootVC = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
        rootVC?.present(editorVC, animated: false, completion: { () -> Void in
            completionHandle(true)
        })
    }
}
```

However, the problem is that it always expect to present from the root viewController. If the user leaves the app from a different VC and then tries the shortcut, I get this error:

> Warning: Attempt to present xxx on (xxxx.ViewController: 0x7f9acc83e000) whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

If the user was in the app and the last view was the root VC, the shortcut from the home screen works great. So how do I make it so it works great regardless of what VC was last used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principle of what you're doing is absolutely right. So why isn't it working?

What I would do is make the window's root view controller a container view controller that *never* gets displaced — all the action happens inside it. That way, the only way the window's root view controller is not in the window hierarchy is that it has a presented view controller. And you could easily find that out by starting by finding out if it has a presented view controller and, if so, present from *that*.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I guess that's my question though, I know the scenario is that the root view controller is presenting VC2, then the user leaves, tries to 3D Touch shortcut back, and I get that error message. So how do I change my code to present from the other VC OR, and this is even better, go back to / call an unwind segue back to the root VC and then present from that.

Comment: Uh, ask it for its `presentedViewController`? Is this a trick question?

Comment: Nevermind that last comment, I just deleted it. It's working now. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a way to force the app back to the root viewController so it just always presents from the first VC?? Because otherwise I have to account for the possibility of the new VC presenting from any VC... and that's just a nightmare of possibilities!

Comment: You mean like telling the root view controller to `dismiss`?

Comment: Exactly. Sorry for the very obvious questions but I haven't dealt with manual navigation stuff beyond segues, unwinds, and some routine navigation controller push/pop operations.